# Statistic and probability

Tags: probability

Suppose a randomly selected family has 3 children and let X be “the number of girls in the family”. How many possible values that a family has exactly 2 girls?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: "How many possible values..." ummm... values of *WHAT*?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n=3$ and $p = \frac{1}{2}$. The outcome of $X$ is "the number of children that are boys." That is, we define a "successful trial" as one where a child is a boy. That has probably $\frac{1}{2}$, assuming it is equally likely for a child to be a boy or girl.

Recall that the binomial PMF is
$$
P(X = x) = \binom{n}{x} p^x ( 1- p)^{n-x}.
$$

Try the problem out, and you can check your answer with the below.

> $$P(X = 2) = \binom{3}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right) = 3 \cdot \frac{1}{8} = \frac{3}{8}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is equally likely to get a boy and a girl, you can be solve this using the binomial distribution formula.